# pygame.mixer.quit() not working

Tags: python, pygame, google-text-to-speech

I was trying to make a text to speech GUI program , here is the code for TTS

```
b = a.get()

blabla = b
tts = gTTS(text=blabla, lang='en-us')
try :
    tts.save("F:/tesst.mp3")
except :
    pass
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((2, 1))
try:
    pygame.mixer.music.load("F:/tesst.mp3")
except :
    pass
mixer.music.play(0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(10)
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.poll()
    clock.tick(10)
mixer.music.set_endevent()
mixer.quit()
os.remove("F:/tesst.mp3")
```

I get Error stating file is already being used by another program, so i cannot run the program recursively .
here is the error

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'F:/tesst.mp3'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not releasing the file after loading it. Try with a context manager and pass a file object instead of a file to the load method:

```
...

with open('F:/tesst.mp3', 'rb') as file_object:
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_object)

mixer.music.play(0)

...
```

Once exited from the context manager the resource will be released.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the Error as 'in speak
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file_object)
pygame.error: Couldn't read from RWops'

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3
import pygame
#from pygame import mixer
import os


profile_name = 'AWS_Account_Name'
SESSION = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
# Create an S3 client
polly_client = SESSION.client('polly')

while 1:
    response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(VoiceId='Joanna',
                    OutputFormat='mp3', 
                    Text = 'This is the test result that we need to play from the python')
    print('text to speech')
    file = open('speech.mp3', 'wb')
    file.write(response['AudioStream'].read())
    file.close()

    pygame.mixer.init()
    #pygame.mixer.music.load('speech.mp3')
    #pygame.mixer.music.play()

    with open('speech.mp3', 'rb') as file_object:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(file_object)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            pass
    #pygame.mixer.music.play(0)
    pygame.mixer.quit()
    pygame.quit()
    os.remove('speech.mp3')
```